# Curl Module not loading on UWAMP and Windows 10?

Tags: uwamp

So I'm trying to install vanilla forums with Uwamp, PHP 7.2.7 and apparently al the extensions enabled, still the installer prompts that Curl isn't enabled. It's ok in php.ini and the dll is in the proper folder, What might be happening?

Restarting Apache or even my computer does have no effect at all.